# Show Database Result in View

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, view

I have a simple Settingsview(via Fragment) which i want to get prefilled with Data from the Database(SQLite). My Databaseresults are in the Settingsfragment.java and now i have no Idea how i get them in the XML(Android:hint).

That is my SettingsFragment.java for now

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import eu.twenty1media.smokestop.model.Asettings;
import eu.twenty1media.smokestop.model.DatabaseHandler;


public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {

    public SettingsFragment(){}



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);

        //Initalize or create Database
         final DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getActivity());
         db.getAsettings(1);



        Button mButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.applysettings);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                db.updateAsettings();
                //db.addData(); wenn Datensatz erst geschrieben werden muss
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Settings saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And this the function getAsettings

```
public Asettings getAsettings(int id)
{
    // 1. get reference to readable DB
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // 2. build query
    Cursor cursor = db.query(DBNAME,
            new String[]{"currency"
                    , "pricepp"
                    , "cigpp"
                    , "name"
                    , "cigperday"
                    , "welcome"
                    , "lastcig"},"id=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) },
            null, // e. group by
            null, // f. having
            null, // g. order by
            null);  // h. limit
    // 3. if we got results get the first one
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();
    // 4. build object

    // 4. build book object
    Asettings asettings = new Asettings();
    //asettings.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
    asettings.setCurrency(cursor.getString(0));
    asettings.setPricepp(Float.parseFloat(cursor.getString(1)));
    asettings.setCigpp(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(2)));
    asettings.setFname(cursor.getString(3));
    asettings.setCigperday(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(4)));
    asettings.setWelcome(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(5)));
    asettings.setLastcig(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(6)));


    Log.d("getAsettings(" + id + ")", asettings.toString());

    // 5. return Asettings
    return asettings;
```

Maybe anyone have a good Tutorial or a Tip for me? I am searching the Web for about an Hour and the only thing I find are ListViewAdapter. But I don't have a Listview, just 6 Variables to put in the right Android:hint in the Textboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow is like this...
1. Instantiate the text views where you want the results to go.
2. Read database and save results as local variables. You can check they exist and have been read correctly by logging then to the console.
3. Write the results from 2 to the views you created in 1.

Comment: I really stuck at the Part where I put my Results in the SettingsFragment.xml. I've seen anywhere something like %1$s but don't know how it works.

Comment: You dont need to put anything in the xml file.

Comment: You dont need to put anything in the xml file. I'm confused as to what you are trying to achieve. Are you wanting the asettings return values to appear on your fragment layout? If so, you need to follow the three steps above

Comment: Problem was, I didn't know that i can change the xml values in the javacode :) Thx guys